# FusionCharts not rendering in Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, asynchronous

I'm using FusionCharts 3.2.1 and Google Chrome 59. The charts don't display in Google Chrome, and this is the error I get :

`DataHandler~update Warning >> Renderer update was postponed due to async`

The same code is **working** on IE

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue.  Chrome version is 59.0.3071.100. In settings after enabling "allow sites to run flash" option and also may be add the site url to the list of sites worked.  This enablihg Flash worked for me in this version as well as in Chrome version, 58.0.3029.110.  But settings looks different between these versions.  Basically select settings and go to advanced settings and under content settings you will see Flash settings. I hope it helps.

Comment: It worked for me too. Thanks! Browser keeps loading till it becomes unresponsive and hangs. This issue occurs in Firefox and Chrome.